# PowerBuilder: create cross-database DataWindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

ALL,

Is there a way to create a cross-database DataWindow inside PowerBuilder?

Its possible to make it work from the script/inside program, but is it possible inside the PB GUI?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in MS SQL Server using synonyms.  I'd suggest that this would be better in a stored procedure that you would then use as the datasource for a datawindow object.